# javascript slider gets reset if I navigate to the second page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function which dynamically updates the page content based on the UI slider values that I am selecting. This is the javascript function.

```
<script>
var masterData=[];  

$(function() {

    $("button").on('click',function(){ loadXMLDoc(); });
    $("[data-slider]")
       .each(function (index) {
           var range;
            var input = $(this);

            $("<span>").addClass("output").attr("id","output"+index)
                .insertAfter(input);
            range = input.data("slider-range").split(",");
            $("<span>").addClass("range")
                .html(range[0])
                .insertBefore(input);
            $("<span>").addClass("range")
                .html(range[1])
                .insertAfter(input);
        })

        .on("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
            var $output =$(this).nextAll(".output:first");
            $output.html(data.value.toFixed(2));
            masterData[$output.attr("id").replace(/output/,"")] = data.value;
            $("#kwBody > tr").each(function() {
               var $cells = $(this).children("td");

               var found=false,count=0,currentCell;
               for (var i=0;i<masterData.length;i++) {
                 currentCell=$cells.eq(i+1);
                 found = parseInt(currentCell.text(),10) >=masterData[i];
                 currentCell.toggleClass("found",found); //add or remove class to highlight 
                 count+=found;
               }
               window.console && console.log(masterData,count);
               $(this).toggle(count==masterData.length); // show if all cells >

            });
        });
});
</script>
```

However, the problem is if I navigate to the second page, the slider gets reset. Also, the function selects the values based on the UI slider only for the page that am currently in. Is there any way to modify it? Probably, if you take a look at [this](http://omega.uta.edu/~rxv1100/slider.php), you can understand the problem that am mentioning.

Comment: The slider is always going to reset because HTTP is a stateless protocol meaning that the state of the controls is lost when a new load is loaded.  A trick that you can do is to make it appear to the user that you're navigating to different pages through the use of hidden divs.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie, how can I achieve that?

Comment: @ramesh I suggest opening a new question for that.